# SQL filter from many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relational-database

I have basic many to many relation set with tables `categories`, `locations` trough `categories_locations` table. Example:

Categories table

```
| ID | Name       |
| 1  | Category 1 |
| 2  | Category 2 |
| 3  | Category 3 |
```

Locations table

```
| ID | Name       |
| 1  | Location 1 |
| 2  | Location 2 |
| 3  | Location 3 |
```

Categories_Locations table

```
| category_id | location_id |
| 1           | 1           |
| 2           | 2           |
| 2           | 3           |
| 3           | 1           |
| 3           | 3           |
```

How to get all location that belong to category 2 and at the same time also belong to category 3? In above example that would result only to location 3!

Filtering with OR is simple. Just a normal left join where category_id IN (matched categories). But how to filter when I want to get only those relation that belong to category1 and at the same time also to category2 (and so on)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    Location_ID 
from CategoryLocations
where Category_ID in (2,3)
group by Location_ID
having COUNT(distinct Category_ID) = 2  -- this 2 is the number of items in the IN list above
```